Component cannot be used as a JSX component. Its type '() => Element' is not a valid JSX element type
I think my Nextjs is broken. The following error occurs in a Parent component. The Spinner Component does not throw an error

Spinner.tsx

 export default function Spinner() {
      return (
        <div className='flex justify-center items-center w-[5%] m-auto'>
         <img 
         src='/asset/kolici-yukleniyor.gif'
         alt="loading..." 
         className='w-full'
         />
        </div>
      )
    }

Parent.tsx
import Link from "next/link";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";

export default function AllPosts({ posts }: any) {
  let loading = true;
  let error = false;

  if (posts) {
    loading = false;
    error = false;
  } else {
    error = true;
  }

  return (
    <div className="responsive-layout">
      <div className="text-black py-8">
        {loading ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : error ? (
          <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-[50vh]">
            <p className="text-center text-base flex justify-center gap-2 items-center">
              An error occurred. Please refresh your browser
            </p>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="grid md:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
            {posts.nodes.map((post: Post, i: number) => (
              <Link key={i} className="card-link" href={`/blog/${post.slug}`}>
                <div className="card" key={i}>
                  <div className="card-body" key={i}>
                    <h3 className="card-title">{post.title}</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


<Spinner/> throws the error:

'Spinner' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its type '() => Element' is not a valid JSX element type.
Type '() => Element' is not assignable to type '(props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => ReactNode'.
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
Property 'children' is missing in type 'Element' but required in type 'ReactPortal'.

<Link> which is native to nextjs also throws an error

'Link' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<Omit<AnchorHTMLAttributes, keyof InternalLinkProps> & InternalLinkProps & { ...; } & RefAttributes<...>>' is not a valid JSX element type.
Type

In case anyone is curious; here are my dependencies' version
    "next": "12",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.1.2",



@types/react version? 2. Declare Spinner as React.FunctionComponent - check if error moves to component declaration instead of use place.


Also @types/react-dom version.

"next": "12",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"typescript": "4.1.2",

The issue with this was the version of react was not compatible with the next version
When building your next application, you can check this nextjs docs for which version of react works with the version of next you're using.
I downgraded to React 17 and the error disappeared
npm i next@12 react@17 react-dom@17 eslint-config-next@12 

Curious to see if anyone who encountered this issue resolved it a different way
